# Pipable string extraction

Tags: bash, shell, string, pipe

I am trying to extract values from an argument which will then be piped to another command in a shell.

The string argument can be zero length, or multiples of 12 (4 char code + 8 digit date). e.g.:

```
123420110404123520110404123620110404
500520110404
```

The output required is the first 4 characters in each group of 12, or a blank string ("") if there is no input. e.g.:

```
123412351236
5005
```

Usage example:

```
[user@machine abc]$ echo 123420110404123520110404123620110404 | [magic set of manipulation commands]
123412351236
```

Note: I have cut, sed & Perl installed. I do not have awk installed.

Comment: what kind of system has sed and Perl but not awk?

Comment: i know. it is also missing a few other basics. alas, i'm not allowed to install anything else, and to request approval would be more painful than productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I could imagine is:

```
echo 123420110404123520110404123620110404 | sed -r 's/(.{4}).{8}/\1/g'
```

or

```
echo 123420110404123520110404123620110404 | sed 's/\(....\)......../\1/g'
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. sed comes through shining once again, just goes to show how powerful it is.